# Does firefox automatically delete previous password?

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management

For some time after generating a new password and allowing firefox to remember it, firefox still remembered the previous saved password of my e-mail service, which shows up every time when I logged into my e-mail (i.e. two passwords show up when I logged into my e-mail, with the respective date on which the password was changed appearing next to the passwords). But at some point recently that previous password no longer shows up.

I do not think I made any change to the setting that would cause such behavior. While it can be a default behavior, I could not find anything.

So what resulted in the deletion of my previous password? Could it be due some malicious actor?

More details:
Firefox version: Firefox 102.7.0esr (recently updated from Firefox 102.6.0esr)
OS version: Windows 10 Education
I am not syncing firefox setting and have no extensions or plugins installed.

Comment: Please add more details. Some details that I think that might be helpful are: name and version of the operative system that you are using and the version of firefox, if you are syncing firefox settings, if you have extensions or plugins installed.

Comment: I have this question, too.  Sometimes poorly-coded sites keep the old password even after the update has occurred.  Sometimes Firefox offers to "update" the password before the password change is complete.  It would be more stable if old passwords were retained until we delete them. But this isn't Firefox Feature Suggestions, so I'm not expecting this suggestion to be taken unless you or I do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

*Firefox* does, indeed, store multiple passwords (and user names) for a site, for example, allowing two different email accounts to be accessed at the same URL. To delete the old password:

- In the URL (location) bar enter `about:logins` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In the *Search Logins* box enter a few characters if the site, Username, or **of the old password that needs to be deleted**, which makes it easy to find.
- Enter the *Firefox* master password to view and/or change the list.
- Click the *Remove* button (trash can icon) at top.

*Voila, c'est fini!*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question is why was my password deleted without any action from my side.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Firefox has always replaced an old password with the new. But, I also always get a little dropdown dialog asking me if I would like to "update" the password, and it never occured to me to say no. I do not recall any setting in Firefox governing this behavior. But frankly, the very idea of having 2 different passwords for the same account on the same website baffles me.